# Making a console application behave like a Windows application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application, and I want it to wait till some event is raised. But it executes the code and exits:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var someObjectInstance = new SomeObject();
    someObjectInstance.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
}

static void SomeEventHandler()
{
    //Some logic
}
```

I want to make my application behave like a Windows application where

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

is called and the message loop is run.

But I don't need neither a message loop nor any form. So it looks like overhead. Is there a more light-weight way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What *aspect* of the behaviour of a Windows Forms app are you really looking for? What's going to raise that event?

Comment: I want it to be possible to wait for some event and then exit the application manually. WinForms implements similar behaviour by Application.Run method.

It's a ConnectionLost event generated by IPC class based on sockets.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First off, unless `SomeObject` is going to raise the event on a separate thread, this won't work without some form of processing in `SomeObject`.  If it's designed that way, however, this is fairly straightforward.

A very efficient way of handling this is to just wait on a WaitHandle:

```
private static ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var someObjectInstance = new SomeObject();
    someObjectInstance.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
    waitHandle.WaitOne(); // Will block until event occurs
}

static void SomeEventHandler()
{
    //some logic
    waitHandle.Set(); // Will allow Main() to continue, exiting the program
}
```

Comment: What namespace is the `ManualResetEvent` in?

Comment: @ArtOfCode System.Threading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  Though I'd recommend `ManualResetEventSlim` today...

Comment: Heh. Don't worry; I have since found another way of doing it so I won't actually be using this.

Answer (score 3):

Add

`Console.ReadLine();` after you attach your eventhandler.

For example..

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\", "*.txt");
        watcher.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void watcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} was created at {1:hh:mm:ss}", e.FullPath, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

Comment: That will just cause the Console application to hang forever, unless somebody types into the Console... Not sure that's the appropriate behavior here, since it has nothing to do with waiting for an (external) event.

Comment: in production I would use a service for this specific example.  But this does work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Sadly, I was incorrect and this won't work, because `Application` is not defined for a console application (Thank you, Reed Copsey).

<strike>This should do the trick, although depending on the sleeptime you choose you could end up hogging the CPU. I feel like there must be a safer way to do this?</strike>

```
while (true)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(this.SleepTime);
}
```

Comment: This is only going to work if you have a Windows Forms message pump, which should never be in a Console application...  "Application" is defined on Windows Forms applications only.  Also, sleeping like this is probably not the best approach, in any case.