# How to switch execution from worker to main thread in a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application

I have a .NET console app, which among other things, listens for various external events (websockets, udp, etc...).  When the event arrives, it does so on a worker thread.  I am trying to marshal the event processing to the main thread (defined as where void Main() was kicked off).

Somewhat [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656250/invoke-delegate-on-main-thread-in-console-application) question have been asked before but it deals with calling out to Windows API.  It allowed me to try out various ideas that ultimately didn't work.

I understand that to marshal threads you must have SynchronizationContext and console apps, unlike WinForms and WPF, do not have it.

I attempted to use a custom [SyncronizationContext](https://veganhunter.net/2016/12/02/synchronizationcontext-in-console-applications/), but it just doesn't marshal threads.

So in a code like this, is it possible to Marshal execution to the main thread?

```
static void Main() {
  WebSocketListener.Register(ReceiveMessages);
}

static void ReceiveMessages(Message message) {
  // fires on a worker thread
  MarshalToMainThread.Post(() => ProcessOnMainThread());
}

static void ProcessOnMainThread() {

}
```

Comment: Why not use async/await? The need for marshalling has gone down to almost nothing in all cases since `async/await`, especially in desktop applications

Comment: A good question, I imagine that you'd have to implement something similar to the "message loop" found in the main thread of Windows application.

Comment: Web sockets in .NET Core (like most networking classes) have asynchronous methods. There shouldn't be any need for raw threads. What is `WebSocketListener` ?

Comment: The reason you can marshal work to the main UI threads of Forms or WPF application is that those threads periodically yield and/or query for incoming messages. The main thread of a console application does not have that by default, but you could create a window handle and introduce a message loop that you could then send messages to from a background thread.

Comment: A simple example for "wait until something happens in another thread" can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3390286/87698

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `async/await` doesn't apply here.  A socket message arrives whenever so I need to process it.  WebSocketListener class just handles the receipt of the message.

Comment: @Heinzi That's exactly right.  I do have a "message loop" of sorts.  Mostly to deal with commands that user enters via Console.ReadLine.  The `ManualResetEvent` object from your link might be an idea to try out.  It handles the flow, though, not marshaling the execution to another thread.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError When you say `window handle`, do you mean creating a hidden window?

Comment: @AngryHacker that's exactly what `await` does and why all networking classes have async methods. This is no different than any web app, all of which work with `async/await`. ASP.NET Core applications *are* console applications. That's just the most basic feature though. Higher-level classes like DataFlow blocks and Channels make processing messages and creating processing pipelines a lot easier. What is WebSocketListener? There's no such library in the BCL.

Comment: @AngryHacker: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @AngryHacker the UI thread in a desktop app doesn't yield, nor does a window handle avoid blocking. Marshallinig will always block if the UI thread is busy. It's quite easy to cause deadlocks if `Invoke` is used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos WebSocketListener is just wrapper around the code that handles all the websockets stuff.  The code that you see just sets up a handler to receive those messages.  And the message arrives when it arrives.  Just cause I stick an async/await in front of it doesn't change anything - it doesn't marshal anything to the main thread.  The reason for marshaling is that I need to update my console UI with information in the received message.